# Simple Camera2 API code in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an app to do some image processing operations on a captured image. I used camera2basic sample as a base to my project but it sometimes takes long time to capture and sometimes crashes which annoying me.

Is there a simple authentic code simpler than camera2basic to use camera2 API with opencv or can I use intent to use the Android camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an image to work with, you can use the standard Android image capture intent to get the default camera app to take a picture for you.

See ["Taking Photos Simply"](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) in the Android developer docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need only the image to work with but I need also to set camera characteristics like auto focus and control the distance. Can I do that using the intent?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of projects which aim to put a robust and simpler wrapper aoerund the Android Camera2 API, and they generally support the earlier camera API also.

The two most poplar at the moment seem to be:

- https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat
- https://github.com/wonderkiln/CameraKit-Android

They are not perfect - take a look at the issues lists and decide yourself.

I have used Fotoapparat and while I did see at least one issue, I found it simpler and more robust than the basic Camera2Basic example code.